# javascript is not executing in browser

Tags: javascript, html, web, execution

I want to run a javascript file in the browser, for that, I created an index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>javascript</title>
    <script src="recamans.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

and linked my javascript file as shown above. The javascript file which I included is

```
let count = 1;
let sequence = [];
let numbers = [];
let index = 0;
let next;


function step() {
  let next = index - count;
  if( next < 0 || numbers[next]){
    next = index + count;
  }
  numbers[next] = true;
  sequence.push(next);
  index = next;
  count++;
}
function setup() {
  let createCanvas = (600, 400);
  numbers[next] = true;
  sequence.push(index);

  for( let i=0; i<10; i++){
    step();
  }
  console.log(sequence);
}


setup();
```

but it is not producing any outputs in the browser.

Comment: `let createCanvas = (600, 400);` What is the purpose of the comma operator there? (It's probably not doing what you think it is) What is your expected output?

Comment: Probably doing nothing since `createCanvas` is never used.

Comment: Your script produces `[ 0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 9, 15, 8, 16, 7, 17 ]` on the console for me. Are you looking in the browser's console for output?

Comment: The output is on the browser console , and not at the browser's page as you may think

Comment: `numbers[next] = true;` will fail as `next` is undefined in`setup`

Comment: This HTML code and script will not actually render a canvas (in case that is what you wanted)

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes I am looking in browser's console for output, though it is producing an output for me on the console, but not in browser's console

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log()
```

doesn't output to the document. You need:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = sequence;
```

Example: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FTLNWQF4PXQO

Comment: And he needs to add a div firstly inside the HTML body

Answer (score -1):

Add 
    document.write(sequence);
after console.log(sequence);